# Failed to detect ServletContainerInitializers for context - Run time error in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc

I am creating spring web-mvc application from scratch without using archetype.
Application build successfully but creating but getting run-time exception
I am using Tomcat-7, I have spring-webmvc in classpath. Please check buildpath image below. Need help to understand issue here

SEVERE: Failed to detect ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/samplerestservice]
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:196)
    ... 15 more

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample.restservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>samplerestservice</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restService-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restService-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**restService-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/conext
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="samplerestservice" />
       <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

**[Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZKSO.png)**

[Deployment Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOYgQ.png)

Comment: Try pointing the beans,mvc and context schema locations to 4.0..For example -  ` http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd` . Similarly change it for `spring-beans` and `spring-mvc` in `restService-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

issue was related to spring framework 4.1.9.RELEASE
After updating to  4.0.5.RELEASE Issue resolved

Comment: add comment as well whether you degraded the jar version again or made some changes

Answer (score 0):

Check this error line:

SEVERE: Failed to detect ServletContainerInitializers for **context with name** [/samplerestservice]

It is expecting some ContainerInitializerObject you define in the code.

Comment: I am not understanding answer clearly. What you mean by expecting some ContainerInitializerObject? Are you suggesting me to add view resolvers?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you want to configure all this stuff by hand? The recommended way to get started with Spring these days is to use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) which auto-configures sensible defaults based on what's in your `pom.xml` and what's on the classpath. Further manual tweaks to configuration can be done in Java and properties files where necessary. It's cleaner, faster and way less hassle than the traditional way. The `spring-boot-web-starter` also embeds an instance of `tomcat` preconfigured to run on port 8080. The spring guys provide an official tool called the [SPRING INITIALIZR](https://start.spring.io/) where you can choose which spring projects to include in your `spring-boot` application and it gives you a project with all the right stuff in the `pom.xml` and the correct folder structure. You just need to import it into eclipse using import -> existing maven project. You can get up and running in minutes, not hours or days.

Comment: I prefer code that does not need special needs like automatic configuration. I like things that can be manually configured and visible. It help me understand every line in code

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the issue you created on the Spring issue tracker, [SPR-13872](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13872), it seems this problem is not strictly related to Spring but may come from something else.